# Position error in ListView GetView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an error in GetView and I believe the problem is with the position variable but everything I have tried has failed to change anything.The ListView is set to display UrlHistory of a WebView. I believe this is the reason my ListVies isn't visible when I open up the activity for it. If it is not then I will have to figure it out later. Regarding the log.e I wanted to see if I could see if it gets data in the LogCat but I can't find the specific line it is in LogCat.

UrlHistoryAdapter.Java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    }

    TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    textView.setText(getItem(position));

    Log.e(Tag, "received data");
    return view;
}
```

LogCat

```
02-02 16:33:04.424 26544-26544/com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser, PID: 26544
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser.UrlHistoryAdapter.getView(UrlHistoryAdapter.java:60)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2406)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1975)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:709)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:770)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1721)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2205)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:725)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2406)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2126)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1286)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6536)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
```

`view` layout doesn't contains view with the id `android.R.id.title`.
I think that the problem is that you used `android.R.id.title` instead of `R.id.title` (without the android at the beginning).
So in order to fix this, you should change `android.R.id.title` to `R.id.title`

Comment: This worked but not after vising another site then viewing the history it is blank again

Answer (score 0):

Its say that your `TextView` is null. Check why it is null.

OBS: I suggest you to use RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Your textview is null,

Try.. textView.setText(getItem(position).toString)
or.. textView.setText(getItem(position)+" ")